# How to update a postgres table with a null test?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to update the name and description in Table 1,

[image]

the values from Table 2.

[image]

If there are no values in Table 2, then do not overwrite the name or description in Table 1 with null. I made 2 requests and ask them to help me optimize them.

Update requests:

```
UPDATE final
SET
  name        = product_info.name
FROM product_info
WHERE final.xml_id = product_info.xml_id
      AND product_info.name NOTNULL;

UPDATE final
SET
  description        = product_info.description
FROM product_info
WHERE final.xml_id = product_info.xml_id
      AND product_info.description NOTNULL;
```

Comment: And wha tis the issue with your queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a single query:

```
UPDATE final f
    SET name = COALESCE(pi.name, f.name),
        description = COALESCE(pi.description, f.description)
FROM product_info pi
WHERE f.xml_id = pi.xml_id AND
      (pi.name IS NOT NULL OR pi.description IS NOT NULL);
```

Comment: It did not work. Overwritten value name =(( 
The "and" structure overwrites the 2 values in table 1. If any value is not null.
https://gyazo.com/dd7a507a3f7cbfba582882438442a841

Comment: @Miksser . . . I have no idea what your comment refers to.  This will assign the `product_info` values to `name` and `description` whenever they are not `NULL`.  That is the same logic as your queries.  Perhaps, however, the "empty" or "NULL" values in your data are actually strings.

Comment: There was everywhere null, but your script still earns after removing AND
       (Pi.name IS NOT NULL OR pi.description IS NOT NULL);
Thanks ^^